# class, interface or enum expected. I don't how to correct

Tags: java

I don't know how to fix this. I tried to put under the scope of the class but it returns with more errors. Is this a curly bracket issue? I looked at other questions but I don't the specific issue at hand.

These are the errors:

> Khalid.java:32: error: class, interface, or enum expected Khalid kald
>   =new Khalid("kald",18, 100,0);
>
> ^ Khalid.java:33: error: class, interface, or enum expected Khalid
>   Lod=new Khalid("Lod", 28,500,0);
>
> ^ Khalid.java:35: error: class, interface, or enum expected
>   kald.setBonus(18, 1.1); ^ Khalid.java:36: error: class, interface, or
>   enum expected System.println(kald.setBonus());

```
class Khalid {

  private String name;
  private int age;
  private double salary;
  private double bonus;

  public Khalid  (String name, int age, double salary, double bonus) {
    this.name=name;
    this.age=age;
    this.salary=salary;
    this.bonus=bonus;
  }

  public double setBonus (double age, double bonus){
    this.bonus=age*bonus;
  }
}

Khalid kald = new Khalid("kald",18, 100,0);
Khalid Lod = new Khalid("Lod", 28,500,0);

kald.setBonus(18, 1.1);
System.println(kald.setBonus());
```

Comment: Change `System.println` to `System.out.println` ... this in addition to possible other errors.

Comment: Your code needs to be in a method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you have your class but you would import it into the main class for initializing your application or maybe import it into another class, you didn't say clearly.

At this point, I believe you want to get the bonus variable. If it is, you must create a getBonus method to recover the variable. This is the good practice.

```
public Double getBonus() {
  return this.bonus;
}
```

Of course, you'd set a bonus value. Then, you can call the method.

```
System.out.println(kald.getBonus());
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you call this code in the same package where class declared?

```
Khalid kald = new Khalid("kald",18, 100,0);
```

If not, declare your class with public visibility:

```
public class Khalid {
```

Also `setBonus()` should return something:

```
public double setBonus(double age, double bonus) {
  this.bonus = age * bonus;

  return this.bonus;
}
```